# Using php or javascript to change picture in a webpage according to some sort of url code

Tags: javascript, php, html

Right now I have a simple website that looks something like this. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9mrV.png

I need a way to change the image and the description at the same time but keep the navbar and title the same as I do not want 100s of pages on for my website.

Would it be best to put image url's into a database and call it out with php along with the description?

Or is there another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your content need to change without leaving the page?
If so, look into using jQuery and AJAX.

goto [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) offical web site, and download the javascript file from them, then upload it to your server.

just before the closing tag for body, insert this:

```
<script src="your.jquery.file.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Now, on your page, a simple way to do this is make sure your img and div tags have id's:

```
<img id="image_to_change src="start.png">
<div id="text_content"></div>
```

After the script tag you included, use another script tag, this time, we're gonna put some javascript of our own in here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#image_to_change').onclick(function(){
         $('#image_to_change').attr('src', 'next_image.png');
         $('#text_content').text("The text you want to insert");
      });
   });
</script>
```

This of course is very crude, but it should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Hi sorry if I wasn't very clear, I need a way to load images into a container if that makes sense.

Comment: Completely. using jquery will be the easiest way. I will update my answer in just a minute.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just needed some idea of where to go with it. Very helpful :)